# draw.rect в словаре не работает в питон

Tags: словари, pygame, python-3.9

Вставил функцию draw.rect в словарь. Функция не работает. Почему? Взарание спаибо.

```
import pygame as pg
pg.init()
import math
sc = pg.display.set_mode((1280, 660))
tp = {0:pg.draw.circle(sc, (25, 4, 11), (1122, 50), 25, 50), 3:pg.draw.circle(sc, (50, 7, 23), (1122, 50), 25, 50), 6:pg.draw.circle(sc, (76, 11, 34), (1122, 50), 25, 50), 9:pg.draw.circle(sc, (101, 14, 46), (1122, 50), 25, 50), 12:pg.draw.circle(sc, (126, 18, 57), (1122, 50), 25,50), 15:pg.draw.circle(sc, (254, 254, 254), (1122, 50), 25, 50), 15:pg.draw.circle(sc, (252, 35, 114), (1122, 50), 25, 50)}
t = 0
run = True
clock = pg.time.Clock()
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            run = False
    sc.fill((0, 0, 0))
    try:
        tp[math.floor(t/3)*3]
    except:
        pass
    pg.display.update()
    t += 1
pg.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: не получается. TypeError: 'pygame.Rect' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поменять код на

```
# это в самое начало файла, сразу после импортов, как новые функции
def test1:
    pg.draw.circle(sc, (25, 4, 11), (1122, 50), 25, 50))

def test2:
    pg.draw.circle(sc, (255, 4, 11), (1000, 100), 25, 50))

...
tp = {1: test1, 2: test2}
...
tp[1]()
```

Если в такой конфигурации заработает, то проблема понятна. Вместо кучи определений, возможно, можно найти какой-то более элегантный способ - но в целом я считаю, что всю идею с массивом функций надо как-то переработать и сделать всю обработку в рамках одной функции, просто с кучей сравнений. Проще и понятнее будет, ИМХО.

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect
https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html

Comment: При указанном коде ошибки не возникает, но квадрат не рисуется. я попробовал по совету другого человека (который походу удалил свой ответ) вызвать функцию через `tp[0]()` и вышла ошибка: TypeError: 'pygame.Rect' object is not callable

Comment: Ошибка идет из строки `tp[0]()`

Comment: Я не особо знаю библиотеку, но не понимаю вообще смысла этой конструкции. Зачем прятать вызов функции в массив и потом пытаться вызвать элемент массива? Вместо tp[0]() пропишите напрямую pg.draw.rect(sc, (254, 254, 254), (1122, 50, 20, 20))

Comment: Я пишу игру которая уже 476 строк кода. У меня не получилось сделать вызов функции и я упростил задачу что бы людям не пришлось изучать все 476 строк кода. задачей будет анимация кружков которые должны появлятся, становится ярче и исчезать. Сейчас не много изменю код и покажу.

Comment: Что ж, упрощение не удалось :). Когда Вы пишете *tp[0]()*, Вы пытаетесь вызвать функцию (на это указывают круглые скобки). Вместе с тем, элемент *tp[0]* - это переменная типа *Rect*. Он - не функция, вызвать его как функцию невозможно, в этом и ошибка. Если Вы хотите по какой-то причине запихать функции в массив и потом вызывать их из массива - Вам нужно явно их определить с помощью оператора def, и только потом записывать в массив (пример: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707589/calling-functions-by-array-index-in-python). Хотя честно говоря, мне этот подход кажется неестественным.

Comment: Ещё небольшое пояснение: когда Вы заполняете Ваш словарь и пишете там *pg.draw.rect(sc, (254, 254, 254), (1122, 50, 20, 20))* - у Вас в словарь не код функции записывается, а результат её вызова с этими параметрами. То есть вместо словаря {1: код функции, 2: код функции, ...} получается {1: Rect, 2: Rect, ...}. А если нужны функции - то пример есть в указанной выше ссылке.

Comment: я в вопросе изменил код что бы было понятнее.

Comment: Добавил пример, но вряд ли такой подход сильно поможет... Надо либо искать дальше, либо переписывать всё, чтобы не было массива функций.

Comment: Ладно, попробую